# Apple Xcode install fails

Tags: xcode, installation

I'm running the Lion release of MacOS (10.7.1) and trying to do my first install of Xcode.

It downloads from the App store OK, then I run the installer, type my password when prompted.  At some point before the end, I get this error message.
The file it is complaining about, iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg, doesn't have anything obviously wrong with it.

```
$ file iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg

iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg: xar archive - version 1

$ xar -tvf iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg

-rw-r--r--      root/wheel        355086 2011-04-04 19:49:27 Bom

-rw-r--r--      root/wheel           536 2011-04-04 19:53:42 PackageInfo

-rw-r--r--      root/wheel     292519053 2011-04-04 19:49:11 Payload
```

I can get a good XML TOC from it with

```
$ xar -tvf iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg --dump-toc=- |more
```

Any ideas on how to get past this?

Thanks,

```
`Sep  4 17:03:59 pvdls-iMac installd[680]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110 "An error occurred while extracting files from the package “iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7fd3c1a5fab0 {NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while extracting files from the package “iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg”., NSFilePath=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root, NSURL=file://localhost/Applications/Install%20Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSDK3_2, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd3c0667b20 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."} {
            NSFilePath = "/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root";
            NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while extracting files from the package \U201ciPhoneSDK3_2.pkg\U201d.";
            NSURL = "file://localhost/Applications/Install%20Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg";
            NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 \"The file couldn\U2019t be opened because it isn\U2019t in the correct format.\"";
            PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSDK3_2";
        }`
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode is not a download - you have to obtain it through the Mac App Store.   And the Mac App Store is under the impression that since I have installed it, I should not be afforded the opportunity to do so again.     See, Steve Jobs quits, and Apple goes all to hell.

Comment: Hmm, there is a process to download something again.  Apple has instructions at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519   -- Quite a lot of people seem to have hit this issue.   Suggestions range from "download again" to "reboot system".   Most times it goes through after 2 or 3 attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a lot of people seem to have hit this issue.

Suggestions range from "download again" to "reboot system". Most times it goes through after 2 or 3 attempts.

For me, on the 7th attempt, the installation went through OK.   I did not need to re-download the 3.2 GB of install data.

I installed it from the command line with:

$ cd /Applications

$ sudo open  Install\ Xcode.app

What an unexpected FAIL on the part of Apple - their SDK won't install smoothly on their current OS release.